# Integrate $\frac{dy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, substitution

The problem is to evaluate the following integral:
$$ \int \frac{dy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} $$
If in the numerator was $y\cdot dy$, it would be absolutely simple (straightforward application of the substitution rule). But in this case, I don't know how to proceed. Any hints welcome.

Comment: Is $x$ a constant??

Comment: Yes, $x$ is a constant.

Comment: $\ln |y+\sqrt{y^2+x^2}|$

Comment: Check by differentiation.

Comment: Then multiply and divide by y and use parts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the identity
$$ \frac{d}{ds} \sinh^{-1} s = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + s^2}}
$$
and change of variable $y \mapsto y/x, dy\mapsto x^{-1}\,dy$.

Note: Although you will get an indefinite integral in terms of $\sinh^{-1}$, you can convert that to logarithmic form.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**:

Put $y=x\tan \theta$ and substitute. 
Then $dy=x\sec^2 \theta d\theta$.

So the integral becomes $$\int \frac{dy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\int \frac{x\sec^2 \theta d\theta}{\sqrt{x^2+x^2\tan^2 \theta}}=\int \frac{x\sec^2 \theta d\theta}{x\sec \theta}$$

Answer (score 2):

The function $\ln(y+\sqrt{y^2+x^2})$ has a "magical" property. By a nice simplification,

$$\left(\ln(y+\sqrt{y^2+x^2})\right)'_y=\frac{1+\dfrac y{\sqrt{y^2+x^2}}}{y+\sqrt{y^2+x^2}}=\frac1{\sqrt{y^2+x^2}}.$$

But you can retrieve this result by the substitution $y=x\sinh(t)$, so that $\sqrt{y^2+x^2}=x\cosh(t)$.

Comment: It should be $\sqrt{y^2+x^2}=|x|\cosh t$, for $x\ne0$.

Comment: @egreg: in this problem, $x$ is a constant and is naturally nonzero. As only its square matters, there is no reason to take it negative.

Comment: You should say this at the outset. On the other hand, the antiderivative you show also works for $x\le0$.

Comment: @egreg: I probably said it implicitly, but I don't recall.